# Bootstrap with CKEditor equals problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, z-index, field, instance

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap modal which contains an instance of CKEditor, but there are a lot of problems...

So basically the fields are left unenabled, they don't look like, but I can't interact with them. Does anybody have a solution to this strange behavior?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - the toolbar buttons work but the text fields within them are uneditable! Did you ever find a fix for this?  I've seen some z-index hacks but none seem to work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

FWIW, I couldn't get [Peter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865664/185839) to work, but the following worked for me, and still keeps the hack in a separate file so you don't have to edit any Bootstrap source files:

```
// bootstrap-ckeditor-modal-fix.js
// hack to fix ckeditor/bootstrap compatiability bug when ckeditor appears in a bootstrap modal dialog
//
// Include this AFTER both bootstrap and ckeditor are loaded.

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  modal_this = this
  $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
    if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
      modal_this.$element.focus()
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Worked for 4.5.5 and Boostrap 2.x. Thank you! :)

Comment: Worked for Bootstrap 3.3.2 and CKEditor 4.6.1. Thanks :)

Comment: Before appling .js hacks, scroll down to @andrew-kapunin answer.  A quick test shows that a simple markup change of removing `tabindex` may be all that's needed.

Answer (score 13):

I just removed the `tabindex` attribute from the modal container, that seems to fix this issue for me.

This was suggested by **fat** here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6996

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution for bootstrap. Just remove the 'tabindex="-1" ' from the modal <div> attributes.

Answer (score 6):

If all the above solutions will not work for you, Please try this:

```
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(document).off('focusin.modal');
    });
```

It worked for me instantly. Here is the source: [tobiv's answer - github](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/issues/374)

Comment: awesome, none of the solution worked for me but this one... Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Update: this just overrides the tabindex="-1".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with the Bootstrap source, I re-attached the focus event handler.

I looked in the Bootstrap Modal (unminified) code to find where the event handler is being defined, under Modal.enforceFocus():

```
var that = this
$(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
  if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
    that.$element.focus()
  }
})
```

I then added a method to CKEditor that ammended this function. You can put this wherever; maybe in a file just for CKEditor overrides.

```
CKEDITOR.bootstrapModalFix = function (modal, $) {
  modal.on('shown', function () {
    var that = $(this).data('modal');
    $(document)
      .off('focusin.modal')
      .on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        // Add this line
        if( e.target.className && e.target.className.indexOf('cke_') == 0 ) return;

        // Original
        if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
          that.$element.focus()
        }
      });
  });
};
```

So now, if I know I am going to load a CKEditor in a Bootstrap modal, I call this method, assuming jQuery is `$`:

```
CKEDITOR.bootstrapModalFix( $('#myModal'), $ )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using CKEditor in the **React-Boostrap Modal**. And I faced the focus issue in the Wiris Mathtype editor. I tried this below two methods that solved my problem.

Paste this below script when the Modal component loads

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].removeAttribute('tabindex')
```

or

Add this attribute to the Modal Component

```
enforceFocus={false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was having these problems. I found this ticket https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6996 which seems to have fixed the issue of the inputs being unselectable for me. I extended the change in this ticket to:

```
if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')){
```

This allows the selects to be usuable as well as the inputs, although repeating the selector is a bit janky it does fix the bugs. Hope this helps you.

Comment: why not use the original fix `hasClass('cke')`?

Comment: Anyone looking for a fix for this issue should use Peter's answer over the one I suggested since it means you dont have to tamper with the source code instead.

Answer (score 1):

The z-index of the bootstrap modal is higher than that of ckeditor panels. So an alternative solution I found was to increase the z-index for ckeditor. Add the following line to ckeditor config.js

```
// app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js
config.baseFloatZIndex = 1E5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/4PACy/

```
        $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
            modal_this = this
            $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
                if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
                // add whatever conditions you need here:
                &&
                !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
                    modal_this.$element.focus()
                }
            })
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap changed focusin.modal to shown.bs.modal

```
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  modal_this = this
  $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
      modal_this.$element.focus()
    }
  })
};
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did try [@Andrew Kapunin 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790576/23705834) by removing tabIndex, but this caused the ckeditor modal to show up irregularly.
Adding to [@Cezar T's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36887521/23705834)
Handling ck-editor's z-index worked:

```
.ck {
  z-index: 100000 !important;

  &.ck-powered-by {
    display: none;
  }

  &.ck-balloon-panel.ck-balloon-panel_arrow_nw.ck-balloon-panel_visible.ck-balloon-panel_with-arrow {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
  }
}
```