# Material-UI TextField inside Popper inside Dialog not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material-UI input elements like TextField are not working / can not get the focus if they are inside a Popper inside a Dialog.

```
<Dialog open={true}>
  ...
  <Popper open={true} style={{zIndex: 1500}}>
    ...
    <TextField />
    ...
  </Popper>
  ...  
</Dialog>
```

The zIndex value for the Popper element is necessary to display Popper in front of the Dialog element.

Simple codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/input-inside-popper-inside-dialog-not-working-9y7rg

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [disableEnforceFocus](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) property on `Dialog` (inherited from `Modal`) to fix this.

```
<Dialog open={true} disableEnforceFocus>
    <SimplePopper />
</Dialog>
```

[image: Edit input-inside-Popper-inside-Dialog-not-working]

Related answer: [CKEditor 4 having problem when used in Material UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046466/ckeditor-4-having-problem-when-used-in-material-ui-dialog/56199900#56199900)

Comment: OMG!!! I've been looking for 2 days on how to fix this. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I had a `Dialog` inside a `Modal`, so I had to `disableEnforceFocus` on both of them. A tip to know who is taking the focus is to press Tab and see where's the focus :)

Comment: Thanks, this issue has been annoying me for months on our projects.. !!!